# Disable/Enable UIButton inside UITableViewCell called multiple times

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

This is a fairly simple situation:

I have custom UITableViewCell class, with it's own properties, outlets and stuff. Among them there are two UIButtons -> **Like** and **Dislike**. You can think of them as liking or disliking comment buttons.

I have added IBActions to them like this (in TableViewController, not CustomCell class):

```
    - (IBAction)likeComment:(UIButton *)sender {

 CustomTableCell *thisCell = (CustomTableCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview]; // to fetch that cell from view
    RSSItem *item = [commentsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   //code to set NSUserDefault value for the comment ID, so it can never be voted for again
   [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

In CellForRowAtIndexPath I check if user default for the current item is selected, if so, I disable buttons (you can like or dislike, not both, so all buttons need to be disabled):

```
if((/* get NSUserDefault for the ID*/) == YES){
    [cell.likeButton setEnabled:NO];
    [cell.dislikeButton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Here, appropriate cell indexPath is called, item for the row fetched and ID for the item is correct.

The problem is that random buttons (in some of the reused cells), besides currently selected one, gets selected (disabled) too. If I try to disable them through outlets, the same thing occurs. That is not acceptable, of course. I have tried various combinations of everything, but apparently I'm going down the wrong way of thoughts.

Any suggestion or a link? Or how to correctly connect those buttons with actions and where.

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and found a simple fix. The selected answer is incorrect. You already are maintaining the information of whether buttons of a certain index of your table need to be enabled or disabled somewhere else by using the NSDefault for that ID.

The way to fix this is within

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Right before your

```
if((/* get NSUserDefault for the ID*/) == YES){
[cell.likeButton setEnabled:NO];
[cell.dislikeButton setEnabled:NO];
```

}

ALWAYS enable the button. Putting this code in an else statement also works.

Note: This works but is not the best solution.

Comment: Thanks @Sam for your answer. I've fixed this a while ago by using tags. The answer is now edited.

Answer (score 3):

**Here's the another perfect solution for the problem......**

**In tableView's CellForRowAtIndexpath method first set the tag for your button**

```
cell.Yourbutton.tag = [Indexpath row];
```

**// call your UIButton event**

```
[cell.youbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**//Method Declaration**

```
- (void)likeEvent:(UIButton *)sender 
{

UIButton *likeButton =  (UIButton *)sender;

if (likeButton.isSelected) {
    [likeButton  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like-default.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else {
    [likeButton  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like-active.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
[likeButton  setSelected:!likeButton.isSelected];
NSLog(@"like:%d",likeButton.isSelected);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because table cells are being reused. Check the documentation of `UITableView` for more information about this. To fix this, maintain the information of whether buttons of a certain index of your table need to be enabled or disabled somewhere else and then enable/disable them in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I know that the cells are reused, and that it is the reason for this problem. I don't disable buttons based on `indexPath.row` value, but item's ID saved as user default. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` i first check that user default, and if the id is there, then disable buttons. But still, it disables more than one cell.